# How to reuse HTTP connection and share it between Sidekiq background jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, crystal-lang

My app sends multiple API requests and get responses in background jobs to third party server. For now every job opens new Http connection and closes it after receiving a response. 
If it's possible to share this connection between  all my app's jobs? 
How to keep it alive while a pool of jobs is in progress? 
How to close it at the end? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what a connection pool is designed for.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#connection-pooling

Comment: Thanks! Is there same functional for Crystal lang?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq.cr/blob/master/src/sidekiq/pool.cr#L55